# Setting focus to specific TKinter entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to set the focus of my program to a specific `entry` widget so that I can start entering data straight-away - how can I do this?

**My current code**

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root,width=100,heigh=100,bd=11)
frame.pack()
label = Label(frame,text="Enter a digit that you guessed:").pack()
entry= Entry(frame,bd=4)
entry.pack()

button1=Button(root,width=4,height=1,text='ok')
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 48):

Use `entry.focus()`:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root,width=100,heigh=100,bd=11)
frame.pack()
label = Label(frame,text="Enter a digit that you guessed:").pack()
entry= Entry(frame,bd=4)
entry.pack()
entry.focus()
button1=Button(root,width=4,height=1,text='ok')
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have the entry prefilled with a variable. The cursor is nevertheless at the first position and you have to got the right to type in or alter the last characters. Is there a way to automatically jump at the end?

Answer (score 5):

I tried this way and it is ok

```
entry= Entry(root)
entry.focus()
entry.pack
```

Comment: Missing parentheses: `entry.pack()`