# Tkinter set focus on Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, setfocus, tkinter-entry

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
userData = tk.Tk()
nbdays = tk.IntVar()
mainframe = tk.Frame(userData, relief= 'raised', borderwidth=1)
tk.Label(mainframe, text = 'Number of days', font = 10).place(x=2, y = 30)
tk.Entry(mainframe, width= 8, textvariable = nbdays).place(x= 200, y= 30)
```

[....]

How do I set the focus on that last tk.Entry(.) widget?

Comment: Use `help(tk.Entry)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting focus to specific TKinter entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626406/setting-focus-to-specific-tkinter-entry-widget)

Answer (score 27):

Use the `focus_set` method which is common to all widgets:

```
entry = tk.Entry(...)
entry.place(...)
entry.focus_set()
```