# python tkinter - How do I get get menu "select all" function to work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to add a menu with "select all" to this program. I want it to select all the text in the answer text box, which is "blank2". I can get the menu and dropdown to work, but when I click on "select all" it gives me an error.
This is the code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *

#function for select all menu item
def select_all(event=None):
    blank2.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
    return "break"

def getDaText():
    src = blank.get()

    if '_' in src:
        dst = src.replace("_", " ")
    else:
        dst = src.replace(" ", "_")

    blank2.insert(0, dst)

def clear_answer():

    blank.delete('0', END)
    blank2.delete('0', END)

main = Tk()
# Creating Menubar
menubar = Menu(main)

# Adding Edit Menu and commands
edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Edit', menu = edit)
#edit.add_command(label ='Cut', command = None)
#edit.add_command(label ='Copy', command = None)
#edit.add_command(label ='Paste', command = None)
edit.add_command(label ='Select All', command=select_all)

Label(main, text=" add or remove underscore ").grid(row=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, pady=1)

blank = Entry(main)
blank2 = Entry(main)

blank.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
blank2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

Button(main, text='Show answer', command=getDaText).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=1)
Button(main, text='Clear', command=clear_answer).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=1)

# display Menu
main.config(menu = menubar)
mainloop()
```

This is the error...

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/mthomas/python_progs/add_or_remove_underscore/add_or_remove_underscore-tk-with-label.py", line 5, in select_all
    blank2.tag_add('sel', '1.0', 'end')
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'tag_add'
```

Comment: You are missing the function `tag_add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the method `tag_add` on an `Entry`-Widget. This Widget does not have a `tag_add` method. Probably you want to use a `Text`-Widget instead.

```
# replace
blank2 = Entry(main)
# with
blank2 = Text(main)
```

Reference:

Entry-Widget: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm

Text-Widget: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm

**Edit**

I have looked for a solution with the `Entry`-Widget and found the following:

```
def select_all(event=None)
    # first set the focus to the entry widget
    blank2.focus()

    # use the selection_range method from the entry widget
    blank2.selection_range(0, END)
```

https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.selection_range-method

[Setting focus to specific TKinter entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626406/setting-focus-to-specific-tkinter-entry-widget)

Comment: Nope, caused main program to fail when "show answer" button is clicked -   
     
 "   return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/mthomas/python_progs/add_or_remove_underscore/add_or_remove_underscore-tk-with-label.py", line 16, in getDaText
    blank2.insert(0, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3121, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0" " 
GUI was also off, answer field was much larger.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Tried to give you an upvote but my user level is too low.

Answer (score -1):

That's should be work too.First : `pip install pyautogui`

```
import pyautogui
def select_all():
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "a") #Fire the CTRL + A event
```