# How to move cursor into a newly created text box upon creation in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working on some code, these functions create a new text box when the enter key is hit, and tab the text box out when the tab key is hit. This is all working well, as can be seen in the functions below, but I would like to be automatically clicked into the text box as soon as it is created so I can immediately start typing, rather than having to click into it manually and then start typing, as this becomes quite slow, especially with the tab function where new boxes are deleted and created a few times. I was wondering if anyone knew a way to automatically put the cursor into the text box, or whether that is possible?

```
 def makeLine(self,event):
    self.x=0
    self.newbox=Text(self.root,width=20, height=3)
    self.newbox.place(x=self.x, y=self.y)
    self.newbox.bind('<Tab>', self.increaseCol)
    self.newbox.bind('<Return>', self.makeLine)
    self.y=self.y+55
    


def increaseCol(self, event):
    event.widget.destroy()
    self.x=self.x+30
    self.tabbedbox=Text(self.root, width=20, height=3)
    self.y=self.y-55
    self.tabbedbox.place(x=self.x, y=self.y)
    self.tabbedbox.bind('<Tab>', self.increaseCol)
    self.y=self.y+55
    self.tabbedbox.bind('<Return>', self.makeLine)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626406/setting-focus-to-specific-tkinter-entry-widget

Comment: That worked great, thanks a lot!

Comment: `focus_force()` also does the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

You can use `focus()` or `focus_set()`to set the focus on a widget:

```
self.newbox.focus()  # also try focus_set()
```

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

[Setting focus to specific TKinter entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626406/setting-focus-to-specific-tkinter-entry-widget)

Comment: Should be `focus_set()` instead of `set_focus()`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Answer updated.